# How can I resolve "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:" errors?

Tags: c#, dictionary, exception, sortedlist

I have an application which got hung up when I tried to add items to it. When I checked the trace file I got this entry:

```
   for (int i=0; i<objects.Count; i++) 
   {
      DataModelObject dmo = (DataModelObject)objects.GetAt(i);
      sl.Add(dmo.Guid, dmo);
   }

}
```

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is `sl`? A SortedList object, I'm guessing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that in a sorted list each key needs to be unique.  So you need to check that you aren't inserting the same key (guid value) twice.  Code shown below:

```
 for (int i=0; i<objects.Count; i++) 
 {        
    DataModelObject dmo = (DataModelObject)objects.GetAt(i);

    if (!sl.ContainsKey(dmo.Guid))
    {
        sl.Add(dmo.Guid, dmo);
    }
 }
```

This will ensure that each key is unique.  If however you are expecting more than one value for each key then you need to use a different type of collection.

Comment: i am testing this, as of now no issues, but you told "If however you are expecting more than one value for each key then you need to use a different type of collection" can you clarify that. Beggining of my question i have mentioned in my trace error " Key in dictionary: '7d210e02-176e-4910-a8aa-0a8606ec95cc'  Key being added: '7d210e02-176e-4910-a8aa-0a8606ec95cc'"

Comment: What I mean by that is that if you have two DataModelObjects with the same guid does that mean they are the same DataModelObject?  If so then the code above is ok.

Comment: you are correct, i have one more question ,previous code will make any application hung??or hung is due to some other reason??

Comment: If you don't have the if statement in to check for the presence of the key (as you didnt) then I suppose your application could hang if you dont catch the exception being thrown.  The code I've posted above won't cause your application to hang so if it's still hanging it's for some other reason.  If this answer fixes your problem can you please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The exception indicates that you adding same `key` twice to your `dictionary`, to solve this issue you can start by insuring that the `DataModelCollection objects` which passed to the function has unique `Key` values (which in your case is a `Guid` data type) `dmo.Guid`

Comment: Can you debug or its on production now?

Comment: when i restart the service the issue gone , now i am able to add objects no hung. For testing debugger not hitting "SatisfyGRs" itself